# Time based incremental load query optimization and index design

Tags: oracle, index-tuning, materialized-view

**Problem**

I try to optimize an extract/load query on a highly normalized table structure. Extract/load is implementing incremental loading using a datetime column to determine only records which have changed since the last extract/load. The extract/load query after joins selects hundreds of millions of records. Each individual table joined has a date column "last_modified" which indicates when a record was modified last. To determine the combined last modified date of an joined record I select the greatest value of "last_modified" of each individual table.

This solution seams not to scale as with hundred of millions of records the filter predicate on the combined "last_modified" does not use any index and requires full table access on all individual tables and takes too long to complete (1h+) just to filter after the combined "last_modified" information.

**Background**

- Oracle database (multiple versions starting from 11g)
- I'm not a dba or have much Oracle know how
- Extract/load process (especially delta loading) is not time critical. If I can guarantee that data is up to date/extracted every 24h its fine.

**Sample**

The following is a simplified sample setup. Assume there is a index on reference_key.

```sql
CREATE TABLE shipment (
    key VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
    last_modified DATE,  -- represents when a record in shipment was last modified
    CONSTRAINT shipment_pk PRIMARY KEY (key)
);

CREATE TABLE invoice (
    key VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
    reference_key VARCHAR2(10),
    last_modified DATE, -- represents when a record in invoice was last modified
    CONSTRAINT invoice_pk PRIMARY KEY (key), 
    CONSTRAINT invoice_fk_shipment FOREIGN KEY (reference_key) REFERENCES shipment(key)
);

CREATE TABLE line (
    key VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
    reference_key VARCHAR2(10),
    last_modified DATE, -- represents when a record in line was last modified   
    CONSTRAINT line_pk PRIMARY KEY (key),
    CONSTRAINT line_fk_invoice FOREIGN KEY (reference_key) REFERENCES invoice(efksid)
);

--To get flat de-normalized records a join like the following is needed

SELECT
    shipment.key || '-' || line.key || '-' || invoice.key AS key,
    GREATEST(line.last_modified, invoice.last_modified, shipment.last_modified) AS last_modified
FROM
    line
    JOIN invoice ON line.reference_key = invoice.key
    JOIN shipment ON invoice.reference_key = shipment.key;
```

To extract/load data since the next 100000 records from a given date I could run the following.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
        shipment.key || '-' || line.key || '-' || invoice.key AS key,
        GREATEST(line.last_modified, invoice.last_modified, shipment.last_modified) AS last_modified
    FROM
        line
        JOIN invoice ON line.reference_key = invoice.key
        JOIN shipment ON invoice.reference_key = shipment.key)
WHERE last_modified > '${target_last_modified}'
ORDER BY last_modified;
FETCH NEXT 100000 ROWS ONLY;
```

The problem this query does not finish/feasible with hundred of millions of records (can even go up to 1-2 billion records).

**What I have tried**

- Indices on the individual last_modified columns seams not to help as it is not considered? when using greatest and still does a full table access scan.
- A functional/and computed column(with an index) seams also not an option as it would need to incorporate multiple tables which is not possible? in Oracle.
- Materialized views to preselect the combined last_modified column and create an index on it. If possible I would like to avoid those. I think I think I could not use a refresh-on-commit materialized view due to the high transactions volume on used tables.

**Questions**

- In this scenario are there any tricks using indices which could speed up my query using the last_modified field.
- If materialized views are my only options what kind of refresh strategies would be feasible. A full refresh would (very likely) take too long. Are there any incremental refresh strategies - if yes would I not just move my extract/load problem from the query to the materialized view?

Thanks for any input/hint given!

Comment: Why do you use a sub-query? You should create indexes on column `reference_key` and maybe also on `last_modified`

Comment: Also, if this is for extract and load purposes, is it really necessary that the data be sorted? Typically sort order only matters for user output. Just removing the `order by` clause should improve your performance drastically.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - there is an index on reference_key - I have clarified this in the sample.

Comment: @pmdba Thanks for comment. you are right that I would not need to order if I would extract all data in one query. But this is not feasible as the remaining data could be dozens of millions. In this case I can only get the next page (in this case with page size 100000). And I need to make sure that the page is in order other wise I can not run the extract query multiple times with just a new "target_last_modified".

Answer (score 0):

You also mention a high transaction rate on your tables. This could lead to problems with your query too, if you don't have enough UNDO retention/space available to complete the query in its entirety before the number of transactions forces an ORA-01555 error.

I would go with a fast refresh materialized view that would just capture incremental changes to the source data: make sure it runs just before you want to do your export, then run the export query against the MV without sorting the output. You won't have transactional consistency or UNDO issues that way, and you won't impose unnecessary overhead on your source tables or your application the way an on-commit MV would.

An excellent summary of materialized view refresh strategies with examples can be found here: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/materialized-views

You would need to create materialized view logs with ROWID on each source table, then include the rowid columns in your MV definition, like so:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON line WITH ROWID
(key, last_modified),
COMMIT SCN INCLUDING NEW VALUES;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON invoice WITH ROWID
(key, last_modified),
COMMIT SCN INCLUDING NEW VALUES;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON shipment WITH ROWID
(key, last_modified),
COMMIT SCN INCLUDING NEW VALUES;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW EXPORT_MV
BUILD IMMEDIATE
REFRESH FORCE
ON DEMAND
AS
SELECT
    line.rowid l_rowid,
    invoice.rowid i_rowid,
    shipment.rowid s_rowid,
    shipment.key || '-' || line.key || '-' || invoice.key AS key,
    GREATEST(line.last_modified, 
             invoice.last_modified, 
             shipment.last_modified) AS last_modified
FROM line
JOIN invoice ON line.reference_key = invoice.key
JOIN shipment ON invoice.reference_key = shipment.key;
```

Make sure to refresh the MV frequently, even if you don't run the export. This will keep the size of the materialized view logs down, keep refresh time relatively short when you *do* want to run the export query, and help you avoid unnecessary spikes in system resource usage related to the MV.

Comment: Thanks for the hint towards materialized view logs! This would indeed be a solution for the delta loading. Is my understanding correct that as soon as export_mv is called I use the materialized log tables and their data is deleted. So if I have problem later on in my extract load all changes in the log tables would be lost? This would help me with the delta loading - but is there any idea also for the initial load in this scenario (getting the initial few hundred million records) - actually I'm more stuck atm with the initial load - to even get to the point of delta loading. Thanks!

Comment: @ClemensK the initial load of the MV will always have to be a complete refresh. You're going to have that problem no matter how you approach this. It is also possible (though rare, as long as they are properly maintained) for the MV Logs to become corrupted or get out of sync, which would force the need for another complete refresh. I would recommend - if you go this route - that you put the MV Logs in their own tablespace, as that will make it easier to manage their storage should they grow faster than expected.

Comment: thanks for the input - I think I got the concept. I was hoping I could avoid mv but it seams like this is the only option. I was hoping there is a index based solution without mv to speed up the extract load query but seams like not an feasible option. I will try to update the question as soon as we decided for an approach